# How define custom classifiers per table in aws glue crawler?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

Ok it is possible to include several S3 paths into single crawler, but what if it is needed to defines custom classifier per table? Is it supported in aws glue cralwers? How define this with couldformation tempalte?

Comment: I have the same problem, define many custom classifiers. Have you found the way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In the crawler, you can specify multiple classifier which might server your purpose. DId you try that? When you create the crawler, it shows the available custom classifiers on the left which you will have to select. Please let me know if it solved your issue.